# Make Global Method for DropDownList BInding

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

i am returning a list from a database like this;

```
ClsCampus campus = new ClsCampus();
List<ClsCampus> camp = campus.GetCampusAll();
Utility.BindComboBox(ComboBoxCampus, camp, "CampusName", "CampusId");
```

I have a class name `Utillity`, in which i have created a static method called `BindComboBox`.

```
public static void BindComboBox(DropDownList listName, List<Object> list, 
    string textField, string valueField)
{
    listName.DataTextField = textField;
    listName.DataValueField = valueField;
    listName.DataSource = list;
    listName.DataBind();
}
```

However, it gives me a compilation error.
**So, How do i write a general purpose method where i can bind a generic list of records to a combobox**

**Error 1**

```
The best overloaded method match for 'KenMISSchool.Repository.Utility.BindComboBox(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList, System.Collections.Generic.List<object>, string, string)' has some invalid arguments D:\Projects\KenMISSchool\Web\forms\student\registration.aspx.cs 20  9   Web
```

Comment: I suppose your ComboBoxCampus is of type DropDownlist? Try passing it as (ComboBoxCampus As DropDownList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `List<ClsCampus>` but method expects `List<Object>` so I would change it to generic way:

```
public static void BindComboBox<T>(DropDownList listName, List<T> list, string textField, string valueField)
{
    listName.DataTextField = textField;
    listName.DataValueField = valueField;
    listName.DataSource = list;
    listName.DataBind();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Utility.BindComboBox<ClsCampus>(ComboBoxCampus, camp, "CampusName", "CampusId");
```

Comment: getting this error, Error 1 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KenMISSchool.Repository.ClsCampus>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' D:\Projects\KenMISSchool\Web\forms\student\registration.aspx.cs 20 46 Web

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Projects\KenMISSchool\Repository\Utility.cs 30 69 Repository

Comment: Are you sure you declared your method like this: `public static void BindComboBox<T>(DropDownList listName, List<T> list, string textField, string valueField)`? It is important to have `<T>` after method name and also do you use at least C# 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar idea, but solved it in another way. I'm not sure if it will work for you, but here's a suggestion:

We implemented an Interface called IDropdownable (not the best name, I know), that forced two properties:

```
public string dropdown_value;
public string dropdown_text;
```

And we then implemented this interface over all classes that needed to be easily bound to dropdownlists:

```
public class Foo : IDropdownable
{
    //Let's say these fields are already in the class:
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private DateTime _date;

    //The interface was then implemented:
    public string dropdown_value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string dropdown_text
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} ({1})", this._name, this._date.Year);
            //Or simpler: return this._name;
        }
    }

}
```

The only thing left was to create a generic function that takes in a `IDropdownable` parameter and outputs the dropdownlist the way you like it (HTML `string`, `SelectList`, `List<SelectListItem>`, ... many options there).

```
public List<SelectListItem> GenerateDDL(
                    List<IDropdownable> items, 
                    string selected_value) 
{ ... }
```

If you want I can give you an approximation of the function.

**Comment**

We did this in MVC2 ASP.Net 4. To be honest, I'm not sure what type should be returned in classic ASP.NET, but I assume some type of List/Array will work.